# Shared memory and IPC Trouble

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I have an exam very early and have a big trouble with this code, it compiling but I have no idea why it blocking.

There isn't error neither warning, compiled with last version of gcc on Ubuntu 16.04, the headers are in `common.h` and they are correct:

```
#include "common.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    pid_t pid;
    int shm = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(Esame), IPC_CREAT | 0664);
    int sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3, IPC_CREAT | 0664);

    semctl(sem, MUTEX, SETVAL, 1);
    semctl(sem, PRENOTATI, SETVAL, 1);
    semctl(sem, APPELLO, SETVAL, 1);

    Esame* e = (Esame*)shmat(shm, 0, 0);
    e->prenotati = 0;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {

        docente(sem, e);
        exit(0);
    }

    int i = 0;

    while (i < NSTUDENTI)
    {
        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
        {
            studente(sem, e);
            exit(0);
        }
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (i < NSTUDENTI + 1)
    {
        wait(0);
        i++;
    }
    shmctl(shm, IPC_RMID, 0);
    semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't post code with external links. Create [mcve] and insert that in to your question.

Comment: "the headers are in common.h and they are correct", let us decide of that.

Comment: You don't seem to like for() loops...

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but it's worth a check; initialising the semaphores to 1 means that they're not available. It looks like you're planning on using one of them as a mutex (they're not), and it's normal for a mutex to be created 'available' to be taken immediately afterwards. So you might be running into problems with semaphores not being takeable (semop() with sem_op=0).